# Swap two digits if their range is descending

Tags: c#, regex

Struggling a bit with regex.

What I want to achieve is accept string and swap two digits if their are divided with "-" and the first is bigger than the second.

Example:

`1,3,5,14-10, 15-20`

Should be replaced with:

`1,3,5,10-14,15-20`

Would be really appreciated for help, cause as far I have only the string validator:

```
"^(?!([ \\d]*-){2})\\d+(?: *[-,] *\\d+)*$"
```

Not sure what would be the practice to implement here my raised question (I mean - modify existing one or make it as it post processing).

Comment: What tool are you using?  This looks like a simple parser might be better suited to handle it.

Comment: It isn't a job for regex. Extract your range with something like `(\d+)-(\d+)`, use a callback function to test the numbers and replace eventually.

Comment: in C#, use `Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`

Comment: string Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement);

Comment: And here is the missing thing - string replacement: how to set the replacement as the swap of two digits?

Comment: I think regexpr is not the right tool for this job, you typically use regex to see if a piece of string actually contains a specific pattern or you are trying to grab values off from a string through patterns. What are you intending to write your program on?

Comment: My application is written with c#.

Comment: I would actually suggest `String.Split` for ',' and then loop through the result and perform another `String.Split` based on '-' then you can do your swapping with the index. It's messy but simple to understand and should work.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Agree with you, as it is the most straight forward way to achieve the goal. But - it would be too much code and really not the best place to use loop. Instead, as Casimir mentioned, better to use a build in functionality of C#, which is `Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a MatchEvaluator instance as third parameter to call a function that returns the replacement string. Example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string sContent = "1,3,5,14-10,15-20";       

      MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(LowerThan);

      Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sContent, @"(\d+)-(\d+)", evaluator));
   }

   public static string LowerThan(Match match)
   {
      if (int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) > int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value)) {
         return match.Groups[2].Value + "-" + match.Groups[1].Value;
      }
      return match.Value;
   }
}
```

Comment: My friend, Thank you - it is way more help, than I expected. Works like a clock, and as far as I understood - this approach would be the best practice for achieving described problem with C#.